# Expressing $j$-nomial coefficients in terms of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Call the $k$th coefficient of $\left(\sum_{i=0}^jx^i\right)^n$ the $j$-nomial coefficient $C(n,k,j)$, so that the numbers $C(n,k,2)$ are just the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$. From the OEIS entries for $j=3$ (https://oeis.org/A027907) and $4$ (https://oeis.org/A008287), it appears that these are given by the formula:
$$C(n,k,j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor}{(-1)}^iC(n,i,2)C(n+k-1-ji,n-1,2),$$
that is,
$$C(n,k,j)=\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor}{(-1)}^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+k-1-ji}{n-1},$$
but I can't seem to find a general proof or come up with one. The formula strongly suggests a combinatorial argument: we have an alternating sum with binomial coefficients, so one is lead to the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I don't know how to use it in this instance.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2654982/573047) and [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cright%5Crfloor%7D%7B(-1)%7D%5Ei%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bk-1-ji%7D%7Bn-1%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Thanks so much!